# Is there any SWF library that can just edit one swf tag?

Tags: tags, flash, edit

I'm working on a project and i need to open a swf file, change contents of a swf tag **without touching other tags**

I've tried "SwfDotNet library" but it does not output the unknown tags. For example if it encounters a "EXPORTASSETS" tag it does not write it to the output SWF because the library is old and supports up to swf version 7 and the tag is new.

Are there any libraries with this capability?

Comment: What is the language used in your project?

Comment: On the flash side I have both AS2 and AS3 swf files. The program which edits the swf can be in any language.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [SWFWire](http://www.swfwire.com) using the [AsyncSWFReaderFiltered class](https://github.com/magicalhobo/SWFWire/blob/master/SWFWireDecompiler/src/com/swfwire/decompiler/AsyncSWFReaderFiltered.as).  For example if you wanted to read only ShowFrame tags:

```
var reader:AsyncSWFReaderFiltered = new AsyncSWFReaderFiltered();
reader.includedTags[1] = true;
reader.addEventListener(AsyncSWFReaderEvent.TAG_READ, function(ev:AsyncSWFReaderEvent):void
{
     trace('Done reading tag #'+ev.result.swf.tags.length);
});
reader.read();
```

All other tags will appear as `UnknownTag`, which are just containers for a `ByteArray`.

Comment: ...and what about writing? I checked the examples and there is a SWF10Writer for example. How can I exatly write the currentReadResult **without any changes**. ( I don't want to specify flash version or anything else myself )

Comment: Use the [Write SWF to a ByteArray](https://github.com/magicalhobo/SWFWire/wiki/Sample-Code) example.  You don't have to specify a flash version.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for as3(flex) that can work in runtime:

1. Load needed swf as bytearray via URLLoader,
2. Parse swf via https://github.com/claus/as3swf util.
3. Made your changes to tags.
4. Generate new bytearray and load it via generic SWFLoader.
   I used that way to change swf version in runtime.

Also take a look at this tools for swf content manipulations:

- http://code.google.com/p/apparat/
- http://swfmill.org/ - you can convert your swf to xml, adjust and convert back to swf.